# Programmatically rotate shapes using coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, shapes

If I have some shapes defined using arrays of coordinates e.g.

```
[[-30, -30], [-30, 30], [30, 30], [30, -30]]
```

and edges defined using:

```
[[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[2,3]]
```

to make a square.

How do I programmatically tell the shape to rotate *at the center against an angle of 0->359 in javascript?

*Or better yet, is there a function which allows me to choose the center of rotation?

**
Currently, I've managed to get the shape to circle the canvas using :

```
var x_rotate = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI /180);
var y_rotate = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI /180);

// for each coordinate
//add x_rotate and y_rotate if coordinate > 0 or subtract if coordinate < 0
```

Comment: Rotating to most angles won't keep precision. Do you want to approximate?

Comment: Yes approximation is fine thanks

Comment: This answer shows you how to rotate points https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521906/3877726

Comment: Blindman it will take me a moment to verify your comment please bare with me

Comment: I may not have the whole picture, but if all you want is to define the rotation origin, then all you need is `ctx.translate(origin_x, origin_y); ctx.rotate(angle); ctx.translate(-origin_x, -origin_y)` https://jsfiddle.net/tj3dgg0c/ and there are [a lot of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649836/using-html5-canvas-rotate-image-about-arbitrary-point)...

Comment: This won't work if there is more than 1 shape in the canvas.

Comment: There are 50 in my fiddle ... And if you need all shapes to have its own angle and angleSpeed, this technique also works https://jsfiddle.net/tj3dgg0c/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go, rotates point `x, y` around point `centerx, centery` by `degrees` degrees. Returns floating values, round if you need to.

To rotate a shape, rotate all the points. Calculate the center if you need to, this does not do it.

[Desmos link with `x` as `a`, `y` as `b`, `centerx` as `p`, `centery` as `q`, and `degrees` as `s`](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8kooagfz0y)

```js
function rotatePoint(x, y, centerx, centery, degrees) {
    var newx = (x - centerx) * Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180) - (y - centery) * Math.sin(degrees * math.PI / 180) + centerx;
    var newy = (x - centerx) * Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI / 180) + (y - centery) * Math.cos(degrees * math.PI / 180) + centery;
    return [newx, newy];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [formular](https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/) for rotating the point around the origin.

```js
function rotate(array, angle) {
    return array.map(function (p) {
        function d2r(a) { return a * Math.PI / 180; }
        return [
            Math.cos(d2r(angle)) * p[0] - Math.sin(d2r(angle)) * p[1],
            Math.sin(d2r(angle)) * p[0] - Math.cos(d2r(angle)) * p[1],
        ];
    });
}
console.log(rotate([[-30, -30], [-30, 30], [30, 30], [30, -30]], 45));
console.log(rotate([[-30, -30], [-30, 30], [30, 30], [30, -30]], 90));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Upvote but the answer above also includes code to re-translate to center of origin, so i'm accepting that one. Very much appreciate your answer though.

Comment: The name r2d is confusing, I guess it should be d2r as the input in the examples is in degrees.

Comment: @ricklamers, you are right. please see edit.

Answer (score -1):

use css transition
and change transform by javascript

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Sorry I didn't explicitly specify I was doing this using a html canvas and the shapes are entirely abstract not html dom elements.

Comment: The OP isn't asking to rotate an HTML element. He is asking to use JavaScript to find new coordinates.